# NullPointerException: uriString

Tags: java, android, json, android-activity

I have received an unexpected error while trying to load my Activity Single Item activity. In brief, this activity is suppose to populate JSON data into the application.

Below is the logcat message recieved:

```
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 3006
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dooba.beta/com.dooba.beta.EventSingleItemActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006):     at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:467)
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006):     at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:457)
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006):     at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:429)
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006):     at com.dooba.beta.EventSingleItemActivity.onCreate(EventSingleItemActivity.java:26)
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-06 21:49:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(3006):     ... 11 more
```

Below is the Event Single Item Activity code

```
public class EventSingleItemActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare Variables
    String list_item_name;
    String list_item_description;
    String list_item_price;
    String single_list_item_description;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_single_item);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        Uri urisingle = Uri.parse(i.getStringExtra("single_list_item_bac"));
        list_item_name = i.getStringExtra("list_item_name");
        single_list_item_description = i.getStringExtra("single_list_item_description");
        list_item_price = i.getStringExtra("list_item_price");

        TextView txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView txtsdescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sdescription);
        TextView txtprice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);

        // Set results to the TextViews
        txtname.setText(list_item_name);
        txtsdescription.setText(single_list_item_description);
        txtprice.setText(list_item_price);


    }
}
```

Below is the main activity page

```
public class EventsActivity extends Activity{

    private static final String URL_WEB_SERVICE = "http://dooba.ca/analytics/ed.php";
    private GridView gv;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> container;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> items;
    public Uri list_item_bac;
    public Uri single_list_item_bac;
    public String list_item_name;
    public String list_item_description;
    public String single_list_item_description;
    public String list_item_price;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.events_list_layout);
        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        container = new ArrayList<Events_List>();
        //download JSON
        listDownload();


        GridView s = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        s.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(EventsActivity.this,EventSingleItemActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("single_list_item_bac",container.get(position).getSingle_list_item_bac());
                intent.putExtra("list_item_name", container.get(position).getList_item_title());
                intent.putExtra("single_list_item_description", container.get(position).getSingle_list_item_description());
                intent.putExtra("list_item_price",container.get(position).getList_item_price());

                startActivity(intent); //start Activity
            }
        });
    }
    public void listDownload(){
        RequestQueue volley = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest json = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, URL_WEB_SERVICE, null, ResponseListener(), ErrorListener());
        volley.add(json);
    }

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> ResponseListener() {
        return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    //your JSON Array
                    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("list_item");
                    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                        container.add(convertirAnuncio(array.getJSONObject(i)));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                gv.setAdapter(new AdapterEvents(getApplicationContext(),container));
                }
            };
        };


    private Response.ErrorListener ErrorListener() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
        };
    }

    //object JSON
    private final Events_List convertirAnuncio(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
        long id = obj.getLong("id"); //id 
        String list_item_name = obj.getString("list_item_name"); 
        String list_item_description = obj.getString("list_item_description");
        String list_item_price = obj.getString("list_item_price");
        String single_list_item_description = obj.getString("single_list_item_description");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(obj.getString("list_item_bac"));
        return new Events_List(id,single_list_item_description,single_list_item_bac, list_item_name,list_item_description,list_item_price, uri);
    }
}
```

Below is the event list code

```
public class Events_List {
public long id;
public String list_item_title;
public String list_item_price;
public Uri single_list_item_bac;
public String list_item_description;
public String single_list_item_description;

public Uri url;

public Events_List(long id, String single_list_item_description, Uri single_list_item_bac, String list_item_title, String list_item_description, String list_item_price, Uri url){
    this.id = id;
    this.list_item_title = list_item_title;
    this.list_item_description = list_item_description;
    this.single_list_item_description = single_list_item_description;
    this.list_item_price = list_item_price;
    this.single_list_item_bac = single_list_item_bac;
    this.url = url;
}

public String getList_item_title()
{
    return this.list_item_title;
}

public Uri getSingle_list_item_bac()
{
    return this.single_list_item_bac;
}

public String getList_item_price()
{
    return this.list_item_price;
}

public String getList_item_description()
{
    return this.list_item_description;
}

public String getSingle_list_item_description()
{
    return this.single_list_item_description;
}


}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

do a null check like this to avoid exception:

```
 Uri urisingle = Uri.parse(i.getStringExtra("single_list_item_bac"));

if(urisingle!=null){
   doSomething()....
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Could you clarify?

Comment: there is lot of places your code could fail..first check whether download json data is proper..if its not proper debug it first..I believe you ar enot getting proper data..please put logs and analyse

Comment: Yeah, the problem is you are passing a null string to the Uri.parse method. Just have to check: str = i.getStringExtra("single_list_item_bac"));  if (str != null) uriSingle = Uri.parse(str);

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I do agree, and have come to the conclusion that the error derives from the following line:  Uri urisingle = Uri.parse(i.getStringExtra("single_list_item_bac")); the json data is proper, and I have also realized that the urisingle variable is not used

Comment: where did you checked is it null or not in above answer??

Answer (score 0):

When you send data with intent you should check first:

```
if(Uri != null)
  // you can sent image as string
  in.putExtra("image", imageUri);
```